# taylor series for a function of matrices

Tags: calculus, analysis, matrices, operator-theory

Say I have a function $(A+B)^{-1}$ where $A$, $B$ are matrix-valued functions of some vector $x$. Can I then expand this function around $x=0$ as:

$$(A+B)^{-1} = (A[0]+B[0])^{-1} - (A[0]+B[0])^{-2} (\delta A + \delta B) + \frac{1}{2}(A[0]+B[0])^{-3} (\delta^2 A + \delta^2 B) + \ldots$$

Comment: You can find Taylor series for a matrix function such as $e^{At}$.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that matrix $C$ is invertible, we have the following formula for the inverse of $C+D$, where $D$ is a matrix of small norm (precisely, we assume $\|DC^{-1}\|<1$): 
$$\begin{split}
(C+D)^{-1}&=C^{-1}(I+DC^{-1})^{-1} = C^{-1}(I-DC^{-1} + (DC^{-1})^2-(DC^{-1})^3+\dots)
\\&=C^{-1}-C^{-1}DC^{-1} + C^{-1}(DC^{-1})^2- C^{-1}(DC^{-1})^3+\dots
\end{split} $$
In your notation, $C=A(0)+B(0)$ and $D=A(x)-A(0)+B(x)-B(0)$. The practicality of further manipulations will depend on how $A$ and $B$ depend on $x$.